# How to stop showing input items in C

Tags: c

Took some element for the matrix, just want to show the output matrix, hiding the matrix elements separately. Could you help please. I have tried as bellow:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  int main() {
  int mat[100][100];
  int row, column, i, j;
  printf("enter how many row and column you want:\n \n");
  scanf("%d", &row);
  scanf("%d", &column);
  printf("enter the matrix:");

  for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < column; j++) {
      scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
  }

  for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < column; j++) {
      printf("%d \t", mat[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean not show what you have entered? You need to disable "echo." Search for that and you'll definitely come up with results.

Comment: Don't you want the user to see what they're typing in?

Comment: there is no standard way to do this.  Platform specific.  Append to your post the platform/compiler you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's not compiler dependant, but platform dependant.
The thing you are looking for is called Termcap for "Terminal capability".

It basically allow you to configure your terminal but it's not necessary simple as you need to understand a bit how a terminal works.

This link should interest you if you are working on linux.
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html

I'm not sure on this point but I think there's a library that allow you to have the same code for linux/windows.

Sorry not to be more precise it's been a long time since I didn't play with that.

Answer (score 1):

use the `tcgetattr()` function on the serial/usb port used by your terminal to get the current setup of the terminal driver.

use the `tcsetattr()` function to update the serial/usb port used by your terminal to turn off the `echo` feature of the terminal driver.

use the `escape` sequences to move the cursor around on the terminal, change colors, etc.

Be sure to save the original settings returned from the call to `tcgetattr()` so you can easily restore the terminal driver to its' original settings.

Read the man page for tcgetattr(3) and tcsetattr(3) for all the details of those commands.  The details can be found online at: `http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html`

Read the man page for `console_codes(4)`.  The details can be found online at: `http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html`